# What is making my compuuter so *-------* unstable?

Tags: bsod, gpu, operating-systems, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-cpu

- Processor:    AMD Ryzen 5 1600
- Motherboard:  [ASrock AB350 pro4](https://download.asrock.com/Manual/AB350%20Pro4.pdf)
- Graphics Card:NVIDIA Geforce 1080
- 2x8GB Mem

Dual boot Windows 10/ Kubuntu

Drivers: as up to date as I can keep them using Primarily SDI (Snappy Driver Installer) with auto installed Nvidia drivers and supplemented with manually installed drivers from Driver Easy

At one point I sent my Graphics card in to the shop and grabbed a lower spec'd Graphics card for the interim. The crashes were MUCH less frequent, though the graphics themselves were impractically laggy for gaming.

Crashlog (still updating):
usually involve...forget the exact words.. "attempted write to nonpaged area" or "attempted write to reserved mem" type messages.

3/26 @3:16- Paged fault in a non paged area - RAM related fault

3/28/2020 @8:37- IRQL not less or equal - RAM

Previous BSODs would be a wide range but mostly graphics related or 'attempted write in a reserved sector' type errors. remember one or two recently said things along the lines of 'reduce overclocking.' (Nothing on this system is overclocked) Or graphics card overheating when the rooms AC was off or too high of a threshold ~80F

Program crashes usually exclusively feature GPU 3D spike from wherever they may be (usually ~60-70% at time of crash to 0 to 100 to 0 to normal levels minus whatever programs cratered from the crash)

A couple previous drives had been 100% disk read crashes shortly before the SSD/HD would become complete scrap (I have a pile of 9+ dead HDDs and SSDs and now refuse to ever use Seagate, Hitachi, or HGST drives for any price)

Any help understanding why my system is like this, and the most optimal fix would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Add to your question: Add OS tags. Remove multi-boot tag. Add link to MB manual. Does the problem occur in both OS? What specs do you want it to have? How much do you want to spend? What slot are you going to put it in? Wipe your hard drive, install OS and get latest drivers from AMD, NVIDIA, and ASRock.

Comment: MB manual? I think in both OS, but I don't push linux as hard, and more stable system so less crashes?? I am fine with current specs I just want the system to be stable and not BSOD any time I play a game that might have bits of spaghetti code or loose ends, or be graphically demanding. I have installed multiple times and gotten most up to date drivers for everything multiple times. System is still unstable and crashes frequently and inconsistently when put under strain.

Comment: 1) Please remove and reseat your memory 2) Does the memory meet or exceed the specifications of the motherboard? There are QV Lists at http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/#Support to check. 3) Is the system overclocked? https://download.asrock.com/Manual/AB350%20Pro4.pdf shows you how; try reverting to default settings, and if that does not help, underclock it. 4) Remove and clean the CPU, put 1/2 cc of new thermal paste on it, and reseat it. See https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/3346-thermal-paste-application-benchmark-too-much-thermal-paste

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Think I finally found it thanks to a games error output wiki of all things.</strike>

1.Uninstalled `microsoft visual C++ 2013 redistributable` packages (x64 And x86)

2.restarted computer

3.reinstalled both packages

Nope. Think that makes it either CPU or memory, perhaps both in different cases.

Comment: Are you by chance overclocking?